# Editing the colour bar of a choropleth map (using matplotlib in python)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have spent the last few hours trying to use my very minimal python knowledge to make choropleth maps. I am quite pleased with the results, but cannot figure out a few features which are bugging me.

[image: [my current map is HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoB65.png)]

The main one of these is that I am not sure how to reduce the number of indices along the legend/colour bar. Ideally i would want maybe 5 - two at the ends, and three in the centre.

I would also like it if I could somehow move the title to the top of the chart, and to change the font to gill sans mt (to match other figures made in arcgis pro).

(any other tips to improve the map would also be appreciated!)

Here is my very basic code as it stands!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)

cax = divider.append_axes("bottom", size="5%", pad=0.1)

plt.title("Median House Prices of London, 2013", loc = 'center',)

gdf.plot('Median_House_Price__2013', 
        ax=ax,
        figsize = [10,5],
        legend = True,
        cax=cax,
        k= 4,
        cmap = 'RdPu',
        legend_kwds = {'label': "House Prices", "orientation": "horizontal"})

ax.set_axis_off();
```

Comment: What is `gdf.plot(...)`? It smell GeoPandas, but your question should be complete of all details (... should ...).

Comment: As you want some non-standard colorbar ticks, it might be easier to set them explicitly. Maybe `cax.set_xticks([20000, 40000, 55000, 70000, 90000])`? Use `ax.set_title("Median House Prices of London, 2013")` to set the title on top of `ax` instead of on top of `cax`.